# How to send a C++ code as a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json

So I am making an IDE using judge0 api. It takes a source_code attribute to be send to compile and run.
Now the problem is this- If I write the code in a single line then it shows error and if write the code in different line using "" after every line then also it gives an error.
Now how should I send that code to API.

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

const source =
  '\
#include <stdio.h>\
int main(void) {\
  char name[10];\
  scanf("%s",name);\
  printf("hello %s",name);\
  return 0;\
    }\
';

axios({
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://judge0.p.rapidapi.com/submissions",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-rapidapi-host": "judge0.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "7b3dddefe1msheb8ab51a9e386f1p114d8ejsn6f6d49dd4d69",
    accept: "application/json",
    useQueryString: true,
  },
  data: {
    language_id: 50,
    source_code: source,
    stdin: "world",
  },
})
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

app.listen(PORT, (req, res) => {
  console.log("Started on port " + PORT);
});
```

Comment: That's not how multiline in javascript works. If you are approaching that way, convert them to template strings (just search for template strings in Google). Also you can add the linefeed character (windows one is `\r\n`).

Comment: Templating solved the problem.Thanks! I saw somewhere on stack overflow how to pass multi-line strings. There it was given the way I wrote in the above code and that didn't work.

Comment: sure can use both, is mostly likely borking as your not including linebreaks and `#include <stdio.h>int main(void) {` causing the issue: https://playcode.io/657046/